# Python API to fetch zip and hash for a git tag, release or hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github

The goal is to fetch a zip ball of a given repo snapshot from the uri. Should be flexible enough to handle releases, tags or any plain ref (partial hash/head etc.). I want to get the zip file as a bytes object. And this thing should handle modern GitHub auth including web, organizations with sso, etc.

I looked at the raw GitHub v3 APIs and some calls are promising but only handle a portion of this. PyGitHub seems to handle a few things well but does not seem to have higher level apis and auth and multipart could become complicated.

Perhaps doing a shallow git clone without any GitHub dependencies is a better solution?

My goal is to have 100% of the files for that snapshot completely unmodified (not even line endings) so I can archive or build them in a different library that does not understand git.

Tried this with gh CLI and it seems it would work but I don’t want to have a bunch of installs to manage other than why pipenv can do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download source in ZIP format from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github)

Comment: This is helpful. Doesn’t solve how I should handle different ways the snapshot can be specified and how to properly auth, but it may be a part of my solution.

Comment: You can replace the `master` with any ref or commit hash. So e.g. you can change `http://github.com/zoul/Finch/zipball/master` to `http://github.com/zoul/Finch/zipball/6f40fe8` to download the repo as of a specific commit. As for authentication, have you tried the example in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962757/python-how-to-download-repository-zip-file-from-github-using-github-api

Comment: I think you are correct on master, and that is very simple. Thanks. I need to test the auth, in my scenario I need to use probably an oauth solution to handle all cases and let the user give my tool read access to that repo.